# Accessing methods on children

Tags: reactjs

I Have a component that receives children and renders those children

```
component = React.createClass({    
    ...some JSX

    {this.props.children}

    ...some JSX
)}
```

At some point I need to loop around the children and call a method that they expose. However, children are not object instances, but rather React representations.

In essence I want to do something like this:

```
var children = this.props.children
React.Children.forEach(children, function(child) {
    child.someAction()
})
```

What's the best way of achieving this?

There is one way that I came across on IRC and it involved cloning the children then accessing them by ref. Though it seems kind of convoluted.

```
// in JSX
{
  newChildren = React.Children.map(children, function(child) {
    return React.CloneElement(child, {ref: child.ref})
  })
}
```

Then do

```
childRefs = this.props.children.map(function(child) {
  return child.ref
})

var self = this;
childRefs.forEach(function(ref){
  self.refs[ref].someAction()
})
```

Though, this feels like I'm working against React.

Comment: Is this call triggered by some event in the parent component, or should it be called at some point in the child component's lifecycle (eg before render, after render)?

Comment: Perhaps the children should listen for a prop change. After rendering the children, the parent should change their props, triggering their methods to fire.

Comment: @Mark I'm trying to figure out the right way for a parent to call a method on the children.

Comment: In general you want your child components to react to prop changes.  There are some exceptions in which you might want to manipulate data post-render.  The implementation will depend on what you want to achieve with your function call. It would help if you could specify this in your question.

Comment: @Mark in essence, I have a from that can dynamically receive Input components that carry validation logic. Even though the inputs can validate themselves onChange, I need them to be validated onSubmit. I want the Form to be able to iterate over the children and call .validate() on them when the user submits.

Comment: Have you considered doing the validation server side?  Usually client-side validation needs to be backed up by server-side validation, as a user could generate whatever post request they want, regardless of your client-side javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In generel you should always try to use to outside-in approach and think of data as immutable.

Providing all children with a `shouldValidate` flag as a prop and then make all children implement the `componentWillReceiveProps` function to do the validation, would be the preferred way as I see it.
Components should in my opinion *never* expose functions/properties to be called from outside as this goes against the idea of React.

An jsx example:

Parent

```
render: function() {
   return this.children.map(Child => {
      return <Child shouldValidate={this.state.submitting}/>
   });
}

onSubmit: function() {
   this.setState({
      submitting: true
   })
}
```

Child

```
componentWillReceiveProps: (nextProps) => {
   if (this.props.shouldValidate) {
      validate();
   }
}
```

Comment: The potential problem I see with this approach is that submit event is not dependent on the validation, so even if validation fails at the component level, the form will be submitted.

Comment: @Hulvej this is an interesting approach that I had not thought of, though Mark has a good point - part of the benefit of calling .validate directly is that .validate returns false if the input is invalid, allowing me to break out of the submit.

Comment: @mark You have a point. This example however was only prove my point about component dependency.
It still seems to me though, that the validation-tree unnecessary. You should validate your data, and each component shouldn't have the responsibility of this. I get the point where a date-component would validate if a date is valid or not. But if you have a model of say, a date + name and a number that together represents some kind of date-model. The parent component should just validate the model as a whole. Let me know if you need a example of what I mean..